# Android BottomSheet jumps up when content changes

Tags: android, android-design-library

I using BottomSheet in my app. This is a sticky bar aligned to the bottom, and shows total price in collapsed mode. User can drag up to see details. My problem is: When the user change the content (add some stocks to the list) and the layout is changing in the collapsed sticky, its jumps up to the full size. No methods called in the BottomSheetCallback, so the transition animations is not working.

BTW i have the same issue in the CollapsedToolbarLayout.

Anybody can help me to avoid this issue?

**UPDATE**

This problem caused by `android:animateLayoutChanges = "true"` in the BottomSheet layout's content. This will cause the same problem in the
`CollapsedToolbarLayout`. I hope this will help somebody :)

Comment: Post your layout and java code here...

Comment: Unfortunately i have a very strong confidentiality contract, so i can not share the code. But i created a sample project, and realised, the main cause: android:animateLayoutChanges = "true" So, if the content is animating the bottomBar (and the collapsed toolbar as well) will open immediately. That is not so good, i need this animations.

Comment: @Apoth do you find a solution for this problem?

Comment: @extmkv, yes. The root of my problem is: i started animation on a collapsed layout. You need to check the bottom bar if it is collapsed, and if yes do not start any view animation inside.

Comment: Removing `android:animateLayoutChanges = "true"` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 11):

Remove `android:animateLayoutChanges = "true"`

Comment: This helped me, additionally I had to set the systemNavBar color to make it work. :)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to change layout with an animation, you have to remove `android:animateLayoutChanges = "true"` in your layout file and call `TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition((ViewGroup) getView().getParent())` before any changes.

In my case, I am using `ConstraintLayout` without definition of `layout_gravity` and I am changing visibility of View.

Comment: yeah, for me, the key was to remove `layout_gravity`, thanks